# FB.ui renders iFrame inside my app iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When i try to render a dialogue for asking user to post on his wall, the dialogue iframe is rendered inside my application iFrame, which hides half of the dialogue :(

You can find screenshot here http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/3076/dialogueq.jpg

Normally it should appear as a lightbox and should be rendered outside the application iFrame.

```
 FB.ui(
 {
  method: 'feed',
  message: 'Gain points and prizes with '+pageName ,
  name: 'Visit our mobile community',
  caption: pageName,
  description: desc,
  link:  'http://mydomain.com/generateLink?pageId='+pageId,
  picture: 'http://mydomain.com/public/img/Logo.png',
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about '+ pageName +' and gain points.'
 },
 function(response) {
    postedOnFb = true;
   if (response && response.post_id) {
   }
 }
);
```

Anybody who has faced similar issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

All of the facebook ui experience that is provided by the facbook js sdk is rendered inside an iframe. Since this is meant to be used in both canvas pages and websites alike, it does not take into account the fact that your page is inside facebook.
More than that, there would probably be some security issues if it was trying to do that, and if it worked it could provide a nice opportunity for people to do [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Since your application is inside a page, and also looks like you are using a screen with small resolution, I suggest that you try to display this dialog in its pop-up version. I agree, it's not as slick but hey, at least the users will be able to see all of it.

To open the dialog in a pop-up, specify the "display" parameter, like this:

```
FB.ui(
 {
  method: 'feed',
  display: 'popup',
  message: 'Gain points and prizes with '+pageName ,
  name: 'Visit our mobile community',
  caption: pageName,
  description: desc,
  link:  'http://mydomain.com/generateLink?pageId='+pageId,
  picture: 'http://mydomain.com/public/img/Logo.png',
  user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about '+ pageName +' and gain points.'
 },
 function(response) {
    postedOnFb = true;
   if (response && response.post_id) {
   }
 }
);
```

You can read about it more here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: Hi, popup is blocked in most cases on the browser if it is nested inside multiple JS function call. Apart from it, the iFrame normally works fine, even on my app. But this problem started appearing lately. It normally appears as a lightbox. Please mention where am i going wrong with this iFrame.

Comment: What do you mean by *lightbox*?  Do you have an example to show, or a screenshot? The screenshot you provided shows the way I know facebook open their dialogs with.

Comment: Hi, There is another place on the same app where i use the same piece of code. But previous iFrame was rendered on click of a button. Please find the screenshot of how the iFrame should be rendered with my mode normally. screenshot is provided at [link] (http://img215.imageshack.us/img215/599/dialogue2.jpg)

Comment: Facebook changed the size of the tab page to 520px (used to be 760px I think) and because of that there's not enough width to contain the dialog. Because of that you should use the *popup* version of the dialog, and just be sure to open it only after a user click.